# \Web Api and Frontend database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, repository, asp.net-web-api

I want to have ASP.NET MVC website that would have some frontend for looking into, adding and other things with data. And then I want to have Web Api for getting data for mobile devices and so. I want to use code first from EF (and I am using Ninject). I create classes for hotel and others. I created HotelManagerContext and database is created and looks good. I am adding data by HomeController and by Repository for this. When I looked at database in Visual Studio data are there. But when I tried to use my HotelsController for Api datacontext is empty. What's wrong? What I forget to set? Something with connection string or what?

This is my ApiController:

```
public class HotelsController : ApiController
{
    private IHotelRepository _hotelRepo { get; set; }

    public HotelsController(IHotelRepository repo)
    {
        _hotelRepo = repo;
    }

    // GET api/Hotels
    public IEnumerable<Hotel> GetHotels()
    {
        return _hotelRepo.GetAll();
    }

    // GET api/Hotels/5
    public Hotel Gethotel(int id)
    {
        return _hotelRepo.Get(id);
    }
}
```

This is part of my controller for frontend:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IHotelRepository _hotelRepo { get; set; }

    public HomeController(IHotelRepository repo)
    {
        _hotelRepo = repo;
    }


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // next methods, for adding data and so
}
```

This is my repository:

```
public class HotelRepository : IHotelRepository
{
    private HotelManagerContext db { get; set; }

    public HotelRepository()
        :this (new HotelManagerContext())
    {
    }

    public HotelRepository(HotelManagerContext hotelManagerContext)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.db = hotelManagerContext;
    }

    public Models.Hotel Get(int id)
    {
        return db.hotels.SingleOrDefault(h => h.hotId == id);
    }

    public IQueryable<Models.Hotel> GetAll()
    {
        return db.hotels;
    }


    public Hotel Add(Hotel hotel)
    {
        db.hotels.Add(hotel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return hotel;
    }
}
```

This is my HotelManagerContext:

```
public class HotelManagerContext : DbContext
{
    public HotelManagerContext() : base("name=HotelManagerContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Hotel> hotels { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit:**

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IHotelRepository>().To<HotelRepository>();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(kernel);
    }
```

**Edit2:**
Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="HotelManagerContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=HotelManagerContext-20121219191411; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|HotelManagerContext-20121219191411.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And I just found that even in HomeController I have empty datacontext. So when I check content of database in Server Explorer there are data which I added (in HomeController). But everytime when I have request page (web api or frontend) datacontext is empty and I can add items there are counting from zero but in database there are already next but can't get it. It's really weird.

Comment: Is your IHotelRepository getting injected as it should? Is HotelRepository.db an object (not null)? Any errors/exceptions?

Comment: I added RegisterServices. I think I do it right. I don't get any erros or exceptions and I am not sure what you mean by this: "Is HotelRepository.db an object (not null)".

Comment: When you debug your apiController can you confirm that the DataContext is empty?

Comment: Yea, it's shows zero count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find solution for this so I create new project and I did everything like in the question. I have same classes, copy and paste code frome question. I can't find any important difference but second time it's working.

I know this isn't exactly solution but in this case I could start my project from begging so I tried it and it really helps. Just don't know where is problem.

Answer (score 0):

What does your connection string look like? "name=HotelManagerContext" seems incomplete. I think you would want to also explicitly specify providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" at the very least (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx)). In any case, it is common practice to put the connection string in the Web.Config file and assign the name there (i.e. name="HotelMamangerContext") then, under normal circumstances, EF will just discover the connection string by convention as long as the name of your DbContext class matches the name of the connection string in Web.Config (otherwise you can still specify it explicitly in the constructor).

On a different note (I don't think this should be related to you current problem), you could consider injecting you DbContext as well. Then you could drop the parameter-less constructor on your repository class unless you need to keep it around for another reason such as unit testing. Also, if you are using Ninject.Web.Common, you may want to consider scoping the instances to the request level (see [InRequestScope](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope)).

```
 ...
 kernel.Bind<HotelMamangerContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
 kernel.Bind<IHotelRepository>().To<HotelRepository>().InRequestScope();
 ...
```

Comment: I post my connection string from Web.Config and I edited my question. Maybe could it help where is problem. It's really weird that I have data in database but in datacontext it's empty. I tried InRequestScope but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried simply getting rid of :base("name=HotelManagerContext")? As I mentioned, EF should be finding your connection string anyways because its name matches your DbContext class name (convention).

Comment: Yea, I have tried. I tried remove just string "name.." and then all of it and same result. I looked in datacontext when debbuging and I got there this in Connection property: `"Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|HotelManagerContext-20121219191411.mdf;Initial Catalog=HotelManagerContext-20121219191411;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE"`. I think it's okay.